# laravel link to assets return 404 for src

Tags: laravel, src

[image]

I have this folder structure and I want to access the files inside resources. So im doing

```
<link href="{{ asset('sass/app.scss') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it says not found so i thought i need to add `resources` so i tried

```
<link href="{{ asset('resources/sass/app.scss') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{{ asset('resources/js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Still i am getting status 404 for both files.
[image]
UPDATE:

I run this command:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't link to `.scss` files directly. There should be a `webpack.mix.js` file in your root folder that dictates how assets are being compiled. Run `npm run dev` to compile your assets to the `public` folder. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix

Comment: @kerbholz you are correct. I am just new in laravel and i am following a tutorial when I came back a few steps saw this command.`let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');` . My questions is why am i getting 404 on those files when I followed step by step.

Comment: You probably didn't follow step by step or the tutorial is crap/wrong. Assets in the `resources` folder should not be linked to directly. Your `webpack.mix.js` tells `npm run dev` to compile `'resources/assets/js/app.js'` to the `public/js` folder and `'resources/assets/sass/app.scss'` to the `public/css` folder, leaving you with `public/js/app.js` and `public/css/app.css` - those are the files you should link to in your `.blade` file. You need to run `npm run dev` though. (If you make constant changes to your asset file, use `npm run watch`, so changes are immediately compiled)

Comment: [Link](https://appdividend.com/2018/02/23/laravel-vue-js-chartjs-tutorial-example/) to tutorial. I believe I did every step until running the `php artisan serve`

Comment: To answer your question "_why am i getting 404 on those files_": because they are outside of the `public` folder, which is "the DocumentRoot" of your project

Comment: In that tutorial it says: "_Now, the next thing is to go to the terminal and type the following command to watch our js and sass files for compilation: npm run dev_" Also, the `.blade` file uses `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />` and `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>`. Looks like you skipped those steps

Comment: @kerbholz im redoing the project let me come back if i still get the same error.I will check to make sure to run npm run dev

Comment: @kerbholz i think i was not able to run that npm run dev can you provide it as asnwer so we can close the OP?with explanation on what `npm run dev does`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: You need to either run `npm run dev`, `npm run watch` or `npm run prod` to compile your assets to "usable" js/css files.

You should never link to assets in your `resources` folder, they will not be available. Anything inside the `public` folder can be linked to.

On your local/dev environment run `npm run dev` to compile your assets to the `public` folder (see `webpack.mix.js` in your project's root folder to know exactly what happens). If you happen to make a lot of changes you can run `npm run watch` instead so you don't have to type `npm run dev` after every change - your assets will automatically be compiled if changes are detected.

Using the vanilla `webpack.mix.js` `npm run dev` will compile `resources/assets/js/app.js` to the `public/js` folder and `resources/assets/sass/app.scss` to the `public/css` folder, leaving you with `public/js/app.js` and `public/css/app.css` - those are the files you should link to in your `.blade` file:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can read more on the "Compiling Assets (Mix)" documentation link:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix

Comment: Hey i have a separate question from OP i hope its ok to ask here. I successfully run with out error but the component is not being rendered. I found a mistake in tutorial. In the tutorial it say to use filename `AddCoin.vue` but in the JS it says `'./components/AddComponent.vue'` so i used `AddComponent` still component is not rendered

Comment: Sure. Best bet is to use `CoinAddComponent.vue` as filename and then use `Vue.component('coin-add-component', require('./components/CoinAddComponent.vue'));` in your `app.js`. Then, inside your `<div id="app">` use `<coin-add-component></coin-add-component>` to show it. Use your browser's DevTools to see any possible errors

Comment: I did what you said, no error and nothing is rendered in the component in welcome.blade.php

Comment: Odd. Maybe create a new project and see if https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend can be of any help. Other than that I can't help, maybe ask a new question with the relevant data